# Name parameter not recognized in Django

Tags: python-3.x

Everytime i get Page not found

i try renaming my views.py, I did my makemigrations and migrate, and nothing happened

Hi, I am working on this python project and I can't get the name parameters to work in my URLs. I have tried everything but my code is not recognizing them.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('estudiantes/', listar_estudiantes, name="listar_alumnos"),
    path('profesores/', listar_profesores, name="listar_profesores"),
    path('', inicio, name="inicio"),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('curso/', listar_curso, name="listar_curso"),
    path('enviar-curso/', crear_curso, name="crear_curso"),
    path('buscar-curso/', buscar_curso, name="buscar_curso"),
    path('curso/<int:id>/', ver_curso, name="ver_curso"),
]
```

Comment: Do you have a traceback or error page with more information? Which URL/path is giving the error? Have you defined `ROOT_URLCONF` in your settings?

Comment: All the URL path above are giving me the error, and yes the ROOT_URLCONF Is defined in my settings

Comment: What is the complete error message/traceback Django is giving you? It's not clear why you think the issue is with the name parameters, a page not found error would not usually mention name parameters in your url conf

Comment: When i try to access any url via any name parameter this is what I get:                        Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/listar_profesores                                      
Using the URLconf defined in ProyectoCoder.urls,                                       
Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

estudiantes/ [name='listar_alumnos']
profesores/ [name='listar_profesores']
The current path, listar_profesores, didn’t match any of these.

Comment: You don't put the name in the URL, the first parameter is the path you access from your browser - the URL for the path named `listar_profesores` is  `127.0.0.1:8000/profesores/`

Comment: ok, so you use the name so you don't have to modify the first parameter?

Comment: The name is used for "reversing" a view name to a path, you use it in `{% url view_name %}` template tags or in a call to `reverse` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/templates/builtins/#std-templatetag-url

Comment: oh, I see, thanks for the fast response!